Gitlab CI/CD Terraform + AWS diretory issue
I am trying to setup gtilab pipeline for serverless application deployment in AWS. Application infrastructure are deployed using Terraform. I am using hashocorp/terraform:ligh image in .gitlab-ci.yml but it is failing in plan stage
here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - 'usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/localsbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

stages:
  - fmt
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

variables:
  TF_ROOT: "terraform"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
  TF_BACKEND_BUCKET: "$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET"
  TF_BACKEND_KEY: "$TF_BACKEND_KEY"
  TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE: "$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"

before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - mkdir -p $TF_ROOT
  - cd $TF_ROOT
  - terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="bucket=$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET" -backend-config="key=$TF_BACKEND_KEY" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"
  - echo "$TR_ROOT"
  - echo "$TFVARS_FILE"
  - ls -al

format:
  stage: fmt
  script:
    - terraform fmt
  only:
    - branches

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
  only:
    - branches

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -out=tfplan
  only:
    - branches

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -auto-approve -out=tfplan
  environment:
    name: dev
    url: "https://mycompany.awsapps.com/start/#"
  only:
    - main
  when: manual

Stage fmt and validate are running fine but failing at plan with below error.

I do not understand why it is saying there are no tf files whereas
there are tf files in project folder.

Is below command going to buildempty directory every time, I run the pipeline?

Can somebody help to fix the below and also help me to understand how image and directory works in gitlab?
$ mkdir $TF_ROOT
 $ cd $TF_ROOT
 $ terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="bucket=bucket=$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET" -backend-config="key=$TF_BACKEND_KEY" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"
 Terraform initialized in an empty directory!
 The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
 with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
 $ terraform plan -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -out=tfplan
 ╷
 │ Error: Failed to read variables file
 │ 
 │ Given variables file  does not exist.
 ╵




I think usually with CI/CD you land in the root of repository. That means if the terraform code is in a subdirectory of the repo, you have to change to it. To me it's also unclear where the TFVARS_FILE is coming from, but it might be due to the lack of my knowledge about GitLab CI.

Removing - mkdir -p $TF_ROOT and - cd $TF_ROOT helped to fix the issue. -mkdir was creating directory under parent directory and main.tf file is within parent directory, not sub-directory.
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - 'usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/localsbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

stages:
  - fmt
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

variables:
  TF_ROOT: "terraform"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
  TF_BACKEND_BUCKET: "$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET"
  TF_BACKEND_KEY: "$TF_BACKEND_KEY"
  TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE: "$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"

before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="bucket=$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET" -backend-config="key=$TF_BACKEND_KEY" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"
  - echo "$TR_ROOT"
  - echo "$TFVARS_FILE"
  - ls -al

format:
  stage: fmt
  script:
    - terraform fmt
  only:
    - branches

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
  only:
    - branches

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -out=tfplan
  only:
    - branches

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform apply -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -auto-approve -out=tfplan
  environment:
    name: dev
    url: "https://mycompany.awsapps.com/start/#"
  only:
    - main
  when: manual


Gitlab has an open issue for specifying a child pipeline's working directory.
terraform fmt  and  terraform validate
terraform fmt and terraform validate don't need terraform files. You can easily run these commands in any empty directory without errors.
terraform plan
This command will throw an exception if you run in an empty directory.
Gitlab terraform wrapper
Gitlab has terraform wrapper which uses TF_ROOT env. This wrapper is deprecated.
Solution
You need to add -chdir=$TF_ROOT to all your steps
here is example .gitlab-ci.yml file
image:
  name: hashicorp/terraform:light
  entrypoint:
    - 'usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/localsbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

stages:
  - fmt
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply

variables:
  TF_ROOT: "terraform"
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION"
  TF_BACKEND_BUCKET: "$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET"
  TF_BACKEND_KEY: "$TF_BACKEND_KEY"
  TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE: "$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"

before_script:
  - terraform --version
  - mkdir -p $TF_ROOT
  - cd $TF_ROOT
  - terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config="bucket=$TF_BACKEND_BUCKET" -backend-config="key=$TF_BACKEND_KEY" -backend-config="region=$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" -backend-config="dynamodb_table=$TF_BACKEND_DYNAMODB_TABLE"
  - echo "$TR_ROOT"
  - echo "$TFVARS_FILE"
  - ls -al

format:
  stage: fmt
  script:
    - terraform -chdir=$TF_ROOT fmt
  only:
    - branches

validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform -chdir=$TF_ROOT validate
  only:
    - branches

plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform -chdir=$TF_ROOT plan -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -out=tfplan
  only:
    - branches

apply:
  stage: apply
  script:
    - terraform -chdir=$TF_ROOT apply -var-file="$TFVARS_FILE" -auto-approve -out=tfplan
  environment:
    name: dev
    url: "https://mycompany.awsapps.com/start/#"
  only:
    - main
  when: manual


